# Finding the upper and lower bounds of a multivariable function

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have the set $A = ${$r(a,b) = \frac{a+b}{a+b+3}, a \in [-1,1], b \in [-1,1]$}.

I started off by saying that $\frac{a+b}{a+b+3} < \frac{a+b}{a+b} = 1$. Thus, A is bounded from above by at least 1. Apparently that's wrong, but I don't understand why. What am I doing wrong, and how should I go about solving a problem like this? Thanks.

Comment: $1$ is an upper bound, but not the best possible upper bound.  It is helpful to note that
$$
r(a,b) = 1 - \frac{3}{a+b+3}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $a$ or $b$ could be negative. Rather, you can do it like

\begin{align*}
\left|\dfrac{a+b}{a+b+3}\right|&=\left|1-\dfrac{3}{a+b+3}\right|\\
&\leq 1+\dfrac{3}{|a+b+3|}\\
&\leq 1+\dfrac{3}{3-|a+b|}\\
&\leq 1+\dfrac{3}{3-|a|-|b|}\\
&\leq 1+\dfrac{3}{3-1-1}\\
&=4,
\end{align*}
an upper bound for that is $4$, meanwhile a lower bound for that is $-4$, of course, this is a rough estimate.

Answer (score 1):

First making

$$
a = \sin u, b = \sin v
$$

we have

$$
r(a,b) \equiv r(u,v) = \frac{\sin u+\sin v}{\sin u+\sin v + 3}
$$

but

$$
\sin u+\sin v = 2\sin(\frac{u+v}{2})\cos(\frac{u-v}{2}) \in [-2,2]
$$

then finally

$$
\frac{-2}{-2+3} \le \frac{a+b}{a+b+3} \le \frac{2}{2+3}
$$

Comment: That's interesting. I don't understand how you get from the second to last, to the last line though. Would you mind explaining that to me, please?